# validateMultiple() does not detect unique

Tags: php, validation, yii2, unique

I have the ff rules :

```
[['auto_id','pos', 'size', 'label'], 'unique', 
 'targetAttribute' => ['auto_id','pos', 'size', 'label'],
 'message'=>'Combination already exist.']
```

but `validateMultiple($models)`  always return true

if my model attributes have these ff values in batch insert :

**Model #1**

```
'auto_1' => 1,
'pos' => 'mid',
'size' => 'small',
'label' => 'myLabel'
```

**Model #2**

```
'auto_1' => 1,
'pos' => 'mid',
'size' => 'small',
'label' => 'myLabel'
```

Comment: This is because the `unique` validator checks the database for uniqueness, so until model 1 is saved to the database, Yii will not detect that model 2 is the same. You could try writing an ad hoc validation method to check uniqueness, or save each model individually and not use `validateMultiple()`.

Comment: @JoeMiller if i try to save each model, does this mean i need track 1 to be deleted if 2 is a duplicate ?

Comment: Basically, yes, if that's how your logic works. An alternative might be to write your own standalone validator. http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#standalone-validators

Comment: @JoeMiller ah ok, I red from the link that unique core validator is designed to work with a model only.